# WebView tutorial presents blank (white) page in emulator, but works fine on device

Tags: android, android-emulator

I followed the instructions in the Android WebView tutorial (at http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html).  When I deploy it to the emulator, it just displays a blank (white) page.  The 3G icon is present in the emulator.  I have the "INTERNET" permission set in my manifest, exactly as described in the tutorial.

And to more clearly confirm that I did it right, when I deploy it to my device (Droid2), it works perfectly fine. immediately displaying the web page specified in the app (www.google.com).

Following this is the relevant Android console output. I would think the last line might be relevant, but I don't know what it means.

> [2010-11-27 19:45:18 - HelloWebView]
>   Android Launch! [2010-11-27 19:45:18 -
>   HelloWebView] adb is running normally.
>   [2010-11-27 19:45:18 - HelloWebView]
>   Performing
>   com.example.hellowebview.HelloWebView
>   activity launch [2010-11-27 19:45:18 -
>   HelloWebView] Automatic Target Mode:
>   Several compatible targets. Please
>   select a target device. [2010-11-27
>   19:45:20 - HelloWebView] WARNING:
>   Application does not specify an API
>   level requirement! [2010-11-27
>   19:45:20 - HelloWebView] Device API
>   version is 8 (Android 2.2) [2010-11-27
>   19:45:23 - HelloWebView] Application
>   already deployed. No need to
>   reinstall. [2010-11-27 19:45:23 -
>   HelloWebView] Starting activity
>   com.example.hellowebview.HelloWebView
>   on device emulator-5554 [2010-11-27
>   19:45:24 - HelloWebView]
>   ActivityManager: Starting: Intent {
>   act=android.intent.action.MAIN
>   cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]
>   cmp=com.example.hellowebview/.HelloWebView
>   } [2010-11-27 19:45:24 - HelloWebView]
>   ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not
>   started, its current task has been
>   brought to the front

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably one of these are helpful:

- http://www.anddev.org/webview-t1409.html
- ["Hello, WebView" tutorial opens the requested address in Android browser and not in my webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893815/hello-webview-tutorial-opens-the-requested-address-in-android-browser-and-not)

Comment: Ok, that gave me a clue.  Enabling "platform notifications" apparently showed me that it was unable to get to the web site, giving me a connection error.  Without that, it just gave me a blank screen.  The next problem is figuring out how to set the proxy settings on the emulator started from the Android SDK/AVD Manager.  I found information on using the "-http-proxy" command-line option for the emulator, but there appears to be no options in the AVD Manager to set the command-line options for the emulator.

Comment: Yes, the avd only manager handles things like density. When younstart the emulator, try adding the -http-proxy option on then command line. Or, in your favorite IDE, there should be an option to set the parameters for command line.