# How to make Web view (Intent.ACTION_VIEW) bigger?

Tags: java, android

I have loaded uri link in a view as follow.

```
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(service + "://"
        + (host.hostname != null ? host.hostname : host.ipAddress) + ":" + port));
```

But the view shows its contents very small as shown in the attached image. Especially like sda1 folder that user has to click. How can make bigger?[image].

EDIT:
I implemented as suggested by one of the members. But the problem is still using the default web browser. A popup came out asking which default browser I want to choose. What I expect is my activity using WebView is the host of to browse the link so that I can control the zoom.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);
        WebView webview = new WebView(this);
        Intent intent = getIntent();        
        webview.loadUrl(intent.getExtras().getString("WEBLINK"));
        webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webview.setInitialScale(150);
    }
```

EDIT1:
My working code is as follow

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity{

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override   
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        Intent intent = getIntent(); 
        myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        myWebView.setInitialScale(150);
        myWebView.loadUrl(intent.getExtras().getString("WEBLINK"));

    }

    public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with a [Webview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html). With the intent ACTION_VIEW, you have no control over the page you are displaying as you are using an external application (browser) that intercepts your intent.

You can check [setInitialScale](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#setInitialScale%28int%29) method for instance.

A better way to handle this would be to handle the display directly on the asp page if you have control over it.

Comment: Yes you are right. I am trying to open attached SDcard through wifi. I use TCP/IP and the url I have is when I convert to String, it is "http://alwayshost:80". Any idea how can I make pass that url to the new activity using intent.

Comment: I have added EDIT. Thanks. It still goes to the default Web browser. Not my WebView.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893815/hello-webview-tutorial-opens-the-requested-address-in-android-browser-and-not#2893868

Comment: Yes good suggestion and I used WebViewClient and now it works. What I implemented is shown in EDIT1.