# Sending a link using push notifications in Azure for Android

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, azure-notificationhub, android-push-notification

I have created a backed in asp.net web-forms successful send a notification for all registered devices but I tired to send a link for example I need to send one push notification include a link When user touch on the notification redirect to mobile browser and open the link.

```
 private static async void SendNotificationAsync()
        {
            NotificationHubClient hub = NotificationHubClient
                .CreateClientFromConnectionString("<Here is my endpoint >", "<hub name>");

            await hub.SendGcmNativeNotificationAsync("{ \"data\" : {\"message\":\"Hello Users \"}}");

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, we could use custom json format and at receiver end convert that string into url. For example,Here’s a sample of the complete JSON payload with a custom "web_link" key containing the URL:

```
 {"data": "{\"message\":\"xxxx\",\"web_link\":\"https://www.example.com\"}"}
```

Then we could override the **OnMessage** function to create Notification, we also could get more detail info from the [Azure document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/xamarin-notification-hubs-push-notifications-android-gcm).

Comment: Dear Tom Sun, when I send it from Azure Portal display Error notification   
 Failed to send test message. Error: {"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"error\":{\"message\":\"Bad Request\",\"code\":\"BadRequest\"}}","responseJSON":{"error":{"message":"Bad Request","code":"BadRequest"}},"status":400,"statusText":"Bad Request"}.
Failed to send test message. Error: {"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"error\":{\"message\":\"Bad Request\",\"code\":\"BadRequest\"}}","responseJSON":{"error":{"message":"Bad Request","code":"BadRequest"}},"status":400,"statusText":"Bad Request"}.
Related events

Comment: Please have a try to include the url in the message with customized format. example: `{"data": "{\"message\":\"xxxx--url\"}"}`. I also upldate the json file

Comment: I want to send a link when user touch on the link open in mobile device web browser

Comment: Sorry, I am not an expert on mobile, but I found another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36623497/how-to-pass-a-url-link-in-notification-and-on-click-it-should-get-open-in-webvi) refer to this. Hope it is useful.

Comment: me too no problem I appreciate you answer Tom Sun.